# HTTP rewriter for docker

Tags: docker

I want to run a docker container, and somehow intercept/modify HTTP responses in the host. That means, basically take every HTTP response coming out of the container, and modify it before sending it back to the user. Is there a standard way to do this in docker?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create a reverse proxy.

All communication in and out of the docker container is done indirectly, trough the proxy. So clients connect to the reverse proxy, the proxy requests the information from the process inside the container. The proxy will also handle the response to the client.

If you simply want to change some headers, a default setup of an apache reverse proxy might be enough. 
See this link on how to set up a reverse proxy using apache:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Other proxy technologies you might consider:
 - Nginx
 - HAProxy

If you want to do more than just changing headers (please fill me in!) than you might have to write some code to handle that for you.

Good luck! And let me know if you need more help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/).  Docker does not change the approach.

Comment: I want to do this in the host, not in the container. When I publish a port, IIUC docker listens on the host and forwards everything on the published port to the container. I want to MITM that forwarding in the host.

Comment: For most routes, Docker uses an iptables NAT rule to redirect the traffic for the published port, so it doesn't go through any user-space process.  

Either way, Docker does not implement the feature you are looking for; you will need another program to do it.  Or edit the Docker source.